# COUNT (*) Statement tips

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table, and it includes the fields:
`country, price and units`
I'm trying to use `SELECT COUNT(*)` to get the sum for each country how many units been sold.
What's the right statement for MySQL ?

Comment: If you want a sum, you can use.. SUM(field)

Comment: Not sure why you got the downvotes, upvoted to compensate. Looks like a valid beginners question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
SELECT  country, SUM(units)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY country
```